Postgres query to find the data from a table where column type is json, using IN with list?
I am using postgres database, i am working with fastapi code where i want to find the data from database using the tags given. The tags column is json type and input will be the python list. I take the python list from user and try to filter the data using that list from database. but it's not working.
Here is the query:
await cur.execute(f"""
    SELECT *
       FROM demo_data.demo_assets
       WHERE ("Tags" ->> 'category') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.category))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'domain') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.domain))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'technology') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.technology))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'topic') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.topic))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'author') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.author))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'platform') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.platform))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'processerfamily') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.processerfamily))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'processortype') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.processortype))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'embeddedboard') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.embeddedboard))});
       """,( data.category, data.domain, data.technology , data.topic, data.author, data.platform, data.processerfamily, data.processortype, data.embeddedboard))

results = await cur.fetchall()

I want a SQL query that will work and fetch the correct data from table.

Parameter replacement doesn't drill into lists, you need to expand them. You can do that by concatenating all the lists rather than specifying them as nested lists in the parameter list.
await cur.execute(f"""
    SELECT *
       FROM demo_data.demo_assets
       WHERE ("Tags" ->> 'category') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.category))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'domain') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.domain))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'technology') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.technology))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'topic') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.topic))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'author') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.author))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'platform') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.platform))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'processerfamily') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.processerfamily))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'processortype') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.processortype))})
       OR ("Tags" ->> 'embeddedboard') IN ({','.join(['%s'] * len(data.embeddedboard))});
       """, (data.category + data.domain + data.technology  + data.topic + data.author + data.platform + data.processerfamily + data.processortype + data.embeddedboard))

results = await cur.fetchall()

Note that this won't work if any of the lists are empty. You can't use IN () in SQL. You'll need more complex logic to add that condition to the query dynamically.
